# Computation of $\int _{-\pi} ^\pi \frac {e^{in\theta} - e^{i(n-1)\theta}} {\mid \sin {\theta} \mid} d\theta .$

Tags: integration, analysis, trigonometry, definite-integrals

I need to compute

$$\int \limits _{-\pi} ^\pi \frac {e^{in\theta} - e^{i(n-1)\theta}} {\mid \sin {\theta} \mid} d\theta .$$

Does anyone see any good strategy? Thanks.

Comment: I have made minor edits to your original post in order to improve its legibility.

Comment: You could rewrite it with euler's formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible integration strategy could be derived from putting
$$
\eqalign{
  & e^{\,i\,n\,\theta }  - e^{\,i\,\left( {n - 1} \right)\,\theta }  = e^{\,i\,\left( {n - {1 \over 2} + {1 \over 2}} \right)\,\theta }  - e^{\,i\,\left( {n - {1 \over 2} - {1 \over 2}} \right)\,\theta }  =   \cr 
  &  = e^{\,i\,\left( {n - {1 \over 2}} \right)\,\theta } \left( {e^{\,i\,{1 \over 2}\,\theta }  - e^{\, - i\,{1 \over 2}\,\theta } } \right) = 2\,i\,e^{\,i\,\left( {2n - 1} \right){\theta  \over 2}\,} \sin \left( {{\theta  \over 2}} \right) \cr} 
$$

Thereby reaching to:
$$
\eqalign{
  & I = \int_{ - \pi }^\pi  {{{e^{\,i\,n\,\theta }  - e^{\,i\,\left( {n - 1} \right)\,\theta } } \over {\left| {\sin \theta } \right|}}\,d\theta }  = \int_{ - \pi }^\pi  {{{2\,i\,e^{\,i\,\left( {2n - 1} \right){\theta  \over 2}\,} \sin \left( {{\theta  \over 2}} \right)} \over {\left| {2\sin \left( {{\theta  \over 2}} \right)\cos \left( {{\theta  \over 2}} \right)} \right|}}\,d\theta }  =   \cr 
  &  = 2\,i\,\int_{ - \pi /2}^{\pi /2} {{{e^{\,i\,\left( {2n - 1} \right)\beta \,} \sin \beta } \over {\left| {\sin \beta \cos \beta } \right|}}\,d\beta }  = 2\,i\,\int_{ - \pi /2}^{\pi /2} {{{e^{\,i\,\left( {2n - 1} \right)\beta \,} {\rm sign}\left( {\sin \beta } \right)} \over {\cos \beta }}\,d\beta }  =   \cr 
  &  = 2\,i\,\left( {\int_0^{\pi /2} {{{e^{\,i\,\left( {2n - 1} \right)\beta \,} } \over {\cos \beta }}\,d\beta }  - \int_{ - \pi /2}^0 {{{e^{\,i\,\left( {2n - 1} \right)\beta \,} } \over {\cos \beta }}\,d\beta } } \right) =   \cr 
  &  = 2\,i\,\left( {\int_0^{\pi /2} {{{e^{\,i\,\left( {2n - 1} \right)\beta \,} } \over {\cos \beta }}\,d\beta }  + \int_0^{ - \pi /2} {{{e^{\,i\,\left( {2n - 1} \right)\beta \,} } \over {\cos \beta }}\,d\beta } } \right) =   \cr 
  &  = 2\,i\,\left( {\int_0^{\pi /2} {{{e^{\,i\,\left( {2n - 1} \right)\beta \,} } \over {\cos \beta }}\,d\beta }  - \int_0^{\pi /2} {{{e^{\, - i\,\left( {2n - 1} \right)\beta \,} } \over {\cos \beta }}\,d\beta } } \right) =   \cr 
  &  =  - 4\int_0^{\pi /2} {{{\sin \left( {\left( {2n - 1} \right)\beta } \right)} \over {\cos \beta }}\,d\beta }  \cr} 
$$

From here various methods can be applied, e.g. :
$$
\eqalign{
  & I =  - 4\int_0^{\pi /2} {{{\sin \left( {\left( {2n - 1} \right)\beta } \right)} \over {\cos \beta }}\,d\beta }  =   \cr 
  &  =  - 4\int_0^{\pi /2} {{{\sin \left( {2n\beta } \right)\cos \left( \beta  \right) - \cos \left( {2n\beta } \right)\sin \left( \beta  \right)} \over {\cos \beta }}\,d\beta }  =   \cr 
  &  =  - 4\int_0^{\pi /2} {\sin \left( {2n\beta } \right)\,d\beta }  - 4\int_{\beta  = 0}^{\pi /2} {{{\cos \left( {2n\beta } \right)} \over {\cos \beta }}\,d\cos \beta }  \cr} 
$$
from which you see that you end with expressions that contain the term 
$
\ln \left( {\cos \beta } \right)
$
thus confirming the answer above that the integral does not converge.

Comment: I was working along those lines until I saw the problem. Maybe there is a Cauchy principal value if $n=m+\frac12$?

Comment: @user5713492 I did not investigate much further than what I reported in the answer, except trying also to apply Vieta's formulas to $cos(2n\beta)$, always keeping $n$ as integer. It would be interesting if you express your deductions for the case  that $n=m+\frac12$

Comment: @GCab Thank you so much for your answer. Actually that is a very bad news for me:-D My problem is actually in the evaluation of \begin{equation}
\frac{1}{(2\pi)^2}\int_{[-\pi,\pi]2}{\frac{1-e^{in\cdot\theta_1}}{1-\cos(\theta_1)\cos(\theta_2)}d\theta_2d\theta_1}-\frac{1}{(2\pi)^2}\int_{[-\pi,\pi]2}{\frac{1-e^{i(n-1)\cdot\theta_1}}{1-\cos(\theta_1)\cos(\theta_2)}d\theta_2d\theta_1}
\end{equation} and I already used that the integration with respect to $\theta_2$ gives the $\mid\sin\mid$ in the dominator. Is here something going wrong? I know that the result should be $\frac{4}{\pi(2n-1)}$.

Comment: @sky90 at a very first glance, it looks to be an integral on the unit sphere (in polar coordinates). Maybe, you can try and change to cartesian coordinates (so $x=cos(\theta_1)cos(\theta_2)$).

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that
$$\lim_{\theta\rightarrow\pi^-}\left(e^{in\theta}-e^{i(n-1)\theta}\right)=\lim_{\theta\rightarrow\pi^-}e^{in\theta}(1-e^{-i\theta})=2e^{in\pi}\ne0$$
So the integral diverges because
$$\lim_{\theta\rightarrow\pi^-}\frac{|\sin\theta|}{(\pi-\theta)}=1$$
So the integrand looks like
$$\frac{2e^{in\theta}}{\pi-\theta}$$
As $\theta\rightarrow\pi^-$.