# Trigonometric integral $\int_{[-\pi,\pi]^2}{\frac{1-e^{-in\cdot\theta_1}}{1-\cos(\theta_1)\cos(\theta_2)}\,d\theta_1\,d\theta_2}$

Tags: integration, analysis, trigonometry

I am trying to compute the following integral [(see here)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1800964/computation-of-int-pi-pi-frac-ein-theta-ein-1-theta-mid/1801451#1801451). Since it seems to be the wrong approach, I am trying to calculate another one which I hope it will give me what I am looking for.

My point is to calculate 
\begin{equation}
a((n,0))=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^2}\int_{[-\pi,\pi]2}{\frac{1-e^{-in\cdot\theta_1}}{1-\cos(\theta_1)\cos(\theta_2)}d\theta_2\,d\theta_1}
\end{equation}

I already computed the first integral in the variable $\theta_2$ and I got

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{(2\pi)}\int_{[-\pi,\pi]}{\frac{1-e^{in\theta_1}}{\mid \sin{\theta_1}\mid}d\theta_1}
\end{equation}

Now using the relation $1-e^{-in\theta_1}=2\sin^2(n\theta_1/2)+i\sin(n\theta_1)$ we can rewrite the integral and get

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{(2\pi)}\left[2\int_0^\pi{\frac{2\sin^2(n\theta_1/2)}{\sin(\theta_1)}+2\int_0^\pi\frac{i\sin(n\theta_1)}{\sin{\theta_1}}d\theta_1}\right]
\end{equation}

Now the second integral should be given by $2\sum_{k=1}^n{\frac{\sin((2k+1)\theta_1)}{2k+1}}$ using [this page](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113728/computing-int-02-pi-frac-sinnx-sinx-mathrm-dx) as reference.

Now I would like to find the first one but I have troubles. At the end I should get $\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^n{\frac{1}{2k-1}}$.

Comment: Something strange is happening there, since $\frac{1-e^{in\theta}}{|\sin\theta|}$ has a non-integrable singularity at $\theta=\pi$ if $n$ is odd.

Comment: What is the context of the problem as a whole? That might make clearer how the problem at $\theta=\pi$ arises.

Comment: @Semiclassical that is the computation of the potential kernel for the simple random walk in 2 dimensions